# How to draw a smooth and filled circle using SDL?

Tags: c, sdl, geometry

I'm using SDL in my C project in which I want to draw a circle that is filled and has a smooth stroke at the same time. Sure, there are functions for each task in SDL: I used `aacircleRGBA()` and `filledCircleRGBA()`. Unfortunately, there is no `aafilledCircleRGBA()` which I would need.

The problem is, that these two functions are both working well separately, but when I try to use them together (drawing circles on each other with the same properties), the size of the circles they draw do not match. One of them (which one is depending on the radius) is always a little bit bigger. This can be seen in the picture below:

```
...
aacircleRGBA(renderer, 300, 300, 100, 90, 160, 20, 255);
filledCircleRGBA(renderer, 300, 300, 100, 90, 160, 20, 255);

SDL_RenderPresent(renderer);
...
```

[image]

As you can see, the `aacircleRGBA()` draws a "taller", while the `filledCircleRGBA()` draws a "wider" circle than the other.

Is there a way to use these two better than I did, or is there any other useful function in SDL that can solve the problem?

Comment: Have you tried calling `aacircleRGBA` *after* `filledCircleRGBA`?

Comment: Yeah, same effect :/

Comment: Have tried to call a filledCircleRGBA with a radius -1 or -2 pixel and then aacircleRGBA ?

Comment: You could try to use different colors and alphas to show more clearly what happens. Then you might want to use the corresponding ellipse functions to see if you can tweak it. I suspect there is something fishy going on in the aa algorithm of SDL.

Comment: Using negative radius the functions don't even draw anything.

Comment: Actually, as I see, the problem is that the drawn circle isn't point symmetric.

Comment: Try replacing `filledCircleRGBA` with `filledEllipseRGBA`, using your current radius for `ry` and `rx = ry-1`. I suspect `filledCircleRGBA` to be drawing a circle too wide by one pixel, or half a pixel.

Comment: @LeventeVarga No, what I mean is that if your radius is 100, do a 98 or 99 filledCircleRGBA then a 100 aacircleRGBA.

Comment: @Tom's I've tried it, but there is a tiny gap between the aa-made circle and the filled circle

Comment: @Nelfeal Tried it, and it solved the problem on the right and left sides, but at the "corners" (at every 45°) a tiny gap appears

Comment: @LeventeVarga Well then look like you will have to do your own aafilledCircleRGBA function. I don't find the documentation for theses function, are there SDL2 basic function are this is like a plugin ?

Comment: @LeventeVarga Damn. I guess you have two choices: call `aacircleRGBA` one more time beforehand with a radius one pixel smaller, or look at [the actual source code](http://www.ferzkopp.net/Software/SDL2_gfx/Docs/html/_s_d_l2__gfx_primitives_8c_source.html#l01436) and try to figure out how to roll your own function (or wait and see if someone can do that for you, but I would doubt it).

Comment: These are the functions of SDL2gfx (SDL2_gfxPrimitives.h)

Comment: @Nelfeal Yeah, it looks like I will need to write my own function for this... Thanks for the help guys!

Comment: @LeventeVarga Well at least your hunch of overdrawning seem rigth. l.1855 `od = (Sint16)lrint(sab*0.01) + 1; /* introduce some overdraw */` in filledCircleRGBA function.

Comment: @Tom's Great, why did they do that that way?

Comment: @LeventeVarga I don't know, but you can start but copy / past the function, remove the overdraw and test ?

Comment: @Tom's That overdraw does nor affect the result. The problem is with the simple ellipse functions, they produce a non-point symmetric circle when I give them the same rx ry. That's the real problem. Even Paint can draw a normal circle...

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit late, I know. I have a very nice solution, but *it may not be the fastest*. You start by drawing that yucky circle with **filledCircleRGBA**, then draw an ellipse with an **aaellipseRGBA**, using **radius+1** as your **rx**, and finally smooth out the top and bottom of the circle with **aacircleRGBA**.

```
void aaFilledCircle(SDL_Renderer* renderer, short x, short y, short rad,
                    char r, char g, char b, char a) {
    filledCircleRGBA(renderer, x, y, rad, r, g, b, a);
    aaellipseRGBA(renderer, x, y, rad+1, rad, r, g, b, a);
    aacircleRGBA(renderer, x, y, rad, r, g, b, a);
}
```